# Yii Undefined yiiactiveform when not using clientValidation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

I use Yii 1.1.14

I use form to capture an email, not using Yii ajaxValidation/clientValidation

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'form-newsletter',
    'action' => null,
    'focus' => array($model, 'email'),
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'role' => 'form',
    ),
)); ?>
```

I got this at js console

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Which is refer to this

```
jQuery('#form-newsletter').yiiactiveform({'validateOnSubmit':true,'validateOnChange':true,'errorCssClass':'has-error has-feedback','successCssClass':'has-success has-feedback','inputContainer':'div.form-group','attributes':[{'id':'NewsletterForm_email','inputID':'NewsletterForm_email','errorID':'NewsletterForm_email_em_','model':'NewsletterForm','name':'email','enableAjaxValidation':true,'clientValidation':function(value, messages, attribute) {
```

I also check that `jquery.yiiactiveform.js` is present.

The question is, i dont want to use the default ajaxValidation/clientValidation, why is it loaded? and why it tells that yiiactiveform is undefined?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you are including a newer version of jQuery than the one Yii includes (2.x for example) for the validation.

Comment: but still, i dont enable clientValidation. that yiiactiveform js shouldn't show up, should it?

Comment: @zmiftah, perfect. That was causing issue in my application! I had two jQuery files of different versions (2.x and 1.10) added in!

Answer (score 2):

If you use other custom javascripts then must use in your layout code for example:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/js/bootstrap.min.js');
```